# Echo items in a list and align them

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php to echo three variable fields :

```html
<li>
     <mark>  <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
     echo   $toprow2['overallRank']     ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['EmployeeName']     ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded']."<br/>";}  ?>
     </mark>
</li>
```

Among these three variables of the list,I want to align the first field "overallRank " to left ,"EmployeeName " to centre and "Total_points_Rewarded" to extreme right.

Below is the code I tried  for the first field:

```html
<li>
    <mark>  <?php  while( $toprow2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3) ) {
                          echo  "<div style = "text-align=left" ."$toprow2['overallRank'] "</div>"."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['EmployeeName'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded']."<br/>";}  ?>
    </mark>
</li>
```

**when I use three divs :**

```html
  echo  "<div style ='text-align:left'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</div><div style ='text-align:centre'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</div><div style ='text-align:right'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</div>";
```

I am not able to align them :Current scenario :

[image]

the first block is the rank,then name and last points -  the three fields that I am trying to echo here.

css used for above situation:

```css
 li mark {
display: inline-block;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
 li mark div {
         display: block;
         margin: 4px;
         padding: 5px;
         min-height: 100px;
         border: 1px solid #eebb55;
         border-radius: 7pt;
         background: grey;
 }
```

**@Abhay has a great solution :css aint working here,though**

current situation:
[image: ww]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex:

```
  echo  "<div class='parent-div'><div class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</div><div class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</div><div class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</div></div>";
```

Your CSS:

```
.parent-div{
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}
.rank,.name,.points{
    width:33%;
}
.name{
    text-align: center;
}
.points{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Small working ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    .parent-div{
        display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
        display: flex;
    }
    .rank,.name,.points{
        width:33%;
    }
    .name{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .points{
        text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class='rank'>Rank</div>
        <div class='name'>Name</div>
        <div class='points'>Points</div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class='rank'>Rank</div>
        <div class='name'>Name</div>
        <div class='points'>Points</div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class='rank'>Rank</div>
        <div class='name'>Name</div>
        <div class='points'>Points</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If continuing with `span` :

```
echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow2['overallRank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow2['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow2['Total_points_Rewarded'] . "</span></div>";
```

Try this  CSS:

```
.parent-div{
        display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
        display: flex;
    }
    .rank,.name,.points{
        display:block;
        width:33%;
    }
    .name{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .points{
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Please mind that I have given class: `parent-div` to all three spans container div.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: thanks for the input.you have used ".name" twice. no issue.But its not readng the css

Comment: i did correct it and tried your codes.Its not able to read the css.Everything looks so perfect. Dont know why.Anyways thanks .God bless.

Comment: @Jane Augustine, Please try the answer one more time, i have made changes in your `echo` stmt as well as in css. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks that u are tryng. The previous solution was perfect.only that the css was not working in it.Now its creating two divs,which is spoilng the look.Why do you think is the css not working.Should we go for inline css?

Comment: Inline css will have same effect as normal one so that's not a solution. Css is working , the fact its not visible because `span` is not a block element and that's why its width can not be defined. By default it takes width of content inside it. 

Can you make a screenshot of how your view is looking after you applied the latest updated answer of mine?

Comment: I tried using your current solution.But i like your previous solution better.M not able to chat.I will update the question.

Comment: I have edited the question and presented the current situation. @Abhay

Comment: @Jane Augustine, I have updated my answer, please try the solution i have suggested in very last of my answer which uses span.

Comment: Also,can we have the name underlined as we hover the name.I tried doing using something like this,a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
} 
a:hover span {
  text-decoration:underline;
}

Comment: For underlining you can use something like: `.rank:hover,.name:hover,.points:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
 }` but did the solution work as you needed?

Comment: it working fine.but this part aint working ---- .points{
     text-align: right;
 }

Comment: Be sure that you have given class name `points` to the third span. If yes then it should work. Also try the example i posted, if you save that example in a new html file and run it in browser, you will see that it works exactly how you need.

Comment: I understand . But don't know why the points class is not working here. I will try some changes. Hold on.

Comment: It worked perfect.had to change some width in the classes,here n there.Thanks a lot.God bless.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```css
 li mark {

   display: inline; /* don't use inline-block */
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
 li mark div {
         float: left; /* here you put the float so it can be after the first li mark */
         display: block;
         margin: 4px;
         padding: 5px;
         min-height: 100px;
         border: 1px solid #eebb55;
         border-radius: 7pt;
         background: grey;
 }

 li mark div:first-child {
      float: left; /* it will put your first div in left side */
 }
 li mark div:last-child {
      float: right; /* it will be in the right side */
 }
```

Also why not remove a width. For example instead being without it in the classes above, this means the width is 100% you could adjust it to `width: 50%` to half.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.